# Error while installing dlib

Tags: c++, python-3.x, c++11, cmake, dlib

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/03/27/how-to-install-dlib/) to install dlib but when I run `pip install dlib` I get

> Collecting dlib
>
> Using cached dlib-19.4.0.tar.gz
>   Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
>
> Running setup.py bdist_wheel for dlib ... error
>
> Complete output from command /home/leo/.virtualenvs/py3_dlib_tutorial/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-4luevi_i/dlib/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpv2rhc6cbpip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
>
> running bdist_wheel
>
> running build
>
> Detected Python architecture: 64bit
>
> Detected platform: linux
>
> Configuring cmake ...
>
> /usr/bin/cmake: /home/leo/anaconda3/lib/libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/cmake)
>
> /usr/bin/cmake: /home/leo/anaconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/bin/cmake)
>
> /usr/bin/cmake: /home/leo/anaconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/bin/cmake)
>
> /usr/bin/cmake: /home/leo/anaconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/bin/cmake)
>
> /usr/bin/cmake: /home/leo/anaconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjsoncpp.so.1)
>
> error: cmake configuration failed!

any suggestions how to fix that?

**Update**

I'm using ubuntu 16.04

also what I've noticed is when I run `sudo pip install dlib` it works but
then I get

```
 (py3_dlib_tutorial) ~$ python
Python 3.6.0 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec 23 2016, 12:22:00) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dlib'
```

**Update**

Seems like a fix prior to this caused the error

I disabled this line in my .bashrc

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/leo/anaconda3/lib`

which was necessery to make `mkvirtualenv` work.
Now `pip install dlib` worked but I still get a similar error

```
python
Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 12:22:00)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/leo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dlib/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .dlib import *
ImportError: /home/leo/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py35.so.1.58.0)
```

Comment: have you installed dlib prerequisites? and what os are you using?

Comment: if you allready installed prerequisites, try install boost python. `sudo apt install libboost-all-dev` and and after that, try `pip install dlib`

Comment: libboost-all-dev is already the newest version (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) that was already installed...

Comment: what is your cmake version?

Comment: with cmake --version i get the same error but   sudo apt-get install cmake says cmake is already the newest version (3.5.1-1ubuntu3).

Comment: I think now it is related to this thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/575505/glibcxx-3-4-20-not-found-how-to-fix-this-error

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this error:

```
python
Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 12:22:00)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux 
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/leo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dlib/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .dlib import *
ImportError: /home/leo/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6: version     `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-
gnu/libboost_python-py35.so.1.58.0)
```

You need to move from Python 3.6 to Python 3.5.
If you are using anaconda, it can be done by setting a new environment:

```
conda create -env_name python=3.5 anaconda
activate env_name
conda install -c menpo dlib
```

This should work and you will have your dlib working fine.